# Образ Снегурочки

Tags: лексика

Существует мнение, что образ Снегурочки связан с проводами зимы, но  он отличается от обряда  сжигания чучела Зимы (Масленицы) своей поэтичностью, сочувствием к растаявшей снежной красавице.

Интересно, это именно Афанасьев записал сюжет со Снегурочкой, в том числе назвал ее имя, которое также вызывает интерес своим необычным формантом  УРК/УРОЧК (этот суффикс обычно используется  для имен собственных Саша – Сашура)?

http://iamhuman.ru/otdykh/1627-kak-u-deda-moroza-poyavilas-snegurochka.html

«Согласно одной из версий, в основу истории положен древний славянский обряд проводов зимы.  Взывая к плодородию, наши предки сжигали или топили соломенное чучело в реке, а гибель девушки из снега во время прыжка через костер – своего рода «облегченная» версия обрядовой традиции. Именно она легла в основу сказки о Снегурочки. В литературные персонажи ее перевел Александр Афанасьев, собиратель русского фольклора. В 1867 году он впервые опубликовал сказки о Снегурочке в своем исследовании «Поэтические воззрения славян на природу»

Comment: А какой вопрос (я не понял)?

Comment: Кто впервые использовал имя Снегурочка и почему этот образ эмоционально противопоставлен образу Зимы, хотя они оба связаны с обрядом проводов зимы?

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос-то в чем?
Если нужна рецензия на этот текст, то тут слишком много положений затрагивается для одной темы.

Про имя "Снегурочка" - это явно не из славянского пантеона, новодел, так сказать. искать, кто первый использовал - довольно неблагодарной занятие...

Насчет суффикса - не согласен.
Снегура-Снегурка-Снегурочка. Вторая степень "ласкательного" диминутива. Какая еще "Шура"?